# python 3.5 matplotlib reading date from csv but can't represent as date on X axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, datetime, matplotlib

I cannot figure this out at all, how do I read a date from csv but I CANNOT represent the date as a label on the x axis. I have tried all the approaches that people have suggested but I cannot get it to work. SO could someone look at the stripped down version of my code and tell me what I am missing please?

a sample of the data being read from csv file

```
2015-08-04 02:14:05.249392,AA,0.0193103612,0.0193515212,0.0249713335,30.6542480634,30.7195875454,39.640763021,0.2131498442,29.0406746589,13524.5347810182,89,57,99
2015-08-05 02:14:05.325113,AAPL,0.0170506271,0.0137941891,0.0105915637,27.0670313481,21.8975963326,16.8135861893,-19.0986405157,-23.2172064279,21.5647072302,33,26,75
2015-08-06 02:14:05.415193,AIG,0.0080808151,0.0073296055,0.0076213535,12.8278962785,11.635388035,12.0985236788,-9.2962105215,3.980405659,-142.8175077335,71,42,33
2015-08-07 02:14:05.486185,AMZN,0.0235649449,0.0305828226,0.0092703502,37.4081902773,48.5487257749,14.7162247572,29.7810062852,-69.6877219282,-334.0005615016,2,92,10
```

stripped down code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(16, 20), dpi=50) #width height inches
data=np.genfromtxt('/home/dave/Desktop/development/hvanal2015s.csv',
     dtype='M8[us],S5,float,float,float',delimiter=',',usecols= [0,1,11,12,13])

my_dates =  np.array([d[0] for d in data]).astype('datetime64[D]')
dates = np.unique(my_dates)
print(dates)

x_list  = []
y_list  = [10,11,12,13]

x_list  = dates

plt.plot(x_list,y_list)

plt.title('hv 20 to 10 ranks',fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('dates')
plt.ylabel('symbol ranks',fontsize=30)
plt.show()
```

and the output as a png file

[image]

Comment: The short answer is `import pandas` or convert your `np.datetime64` objects to `datetime.datetime` objects.

Comment: @tcaswell you are a gentleman and a scholar, I was SO close but no cigar! thanks so much for helping the truly stupid with this. sometime in the past I had something like your answer but I messed up. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: This is a serious pain point for mpl, but it is non-trivial to fix.  pandas supports datetime64 objects via a cython based box which is deeply embedded in their Series classes so we can not just port it over.  It is probably a couple of days - a week of solid effort, but no one has found the time.

Comment: I understand and the problem was explained to me in depth. I am staying away from Pandas as I am a little concerned that one day it might become proprietary, I have no evidence that this will happen just a hunch. I really like Matplotlib and am having a blast using it. I am new to python as well, this is my third program as I don't have a lot of coding time. You and  Stanley R have helped me ALOT thank you so much

Comment: pandas is BSD licensed, it can not become proprietary.  Someone could fork the source and start selling it, but it is very unlikely that they would ever supplant the current community around pandas.  There are actually a couple of proprietary dataframe like libraries and they are going the other way and opening up (see dato's SFrame).

Comment: There may be reasons to not use pandas, but concern over the license is not one of them.  If you are parsing CSV and playing around with DataFrame like data structure it will make your like much better.

Comment: hi there, thank you for the reassurance and I have played around with Pandas in the past. It's a fine piece of software and thanks to your observations I will probably revisit it in the future. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matplotlib` does not support `numpy` `datetime64` objects, you need to convert it to python `datetime` object and then select `formatter` like in code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, 1) #width height inches
data=np.genfromtxt('data',
     dtype='M8[us],S5,float,float,float',delimiter=',',usecols= [0,1,11,12,13])

my_dates =  np.array([d[0] for d in data]).astype('datetime64[D]')
dates = np.unique(my_dates)
print(dates)
x_list = []
x_list[:] = dates.astype(datetime)
y_list  = [10,11,12,13]
plt.plot(x_list,y_list)
plt.title('hv 20 to 10 ranks',fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('dates',fontsize=16)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.ylabel('symbol ranks',fontsize=30)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: WOW thanks so much for this GREAT assist. I would have spent hours in the wilderness getting this wrong. Really really helped me out alot have an excellent holiday.